# Timestamp YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssTZD in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, datetime-format

I am struggling the current UTC time into this format using Python:
`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssTZD` (e.g. 1997-07-16T19:20:30.000+00:00)

Comment: You're struggling ey? with what exactly? What have you tried? Or are you just struggling in general to find any pointers at all? Trying to pinpoint the effort we should be going in to this with.

Comment: Does it matter if you report microseconds instead of milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this. With using `datetime` and `dateutil`

```
In [1]: from dateutil.tz import tzoffset
In [2]: from datetime import datetime
In [3]: now = datetime.now(tzoffset('EDT', +4*60*60))
In [4]: print now.isoformat()
2016-05-28T01:43:14.702253+04:00
```

For remove milliseconds use something like this.

```
now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT:%H:%M:%S")
```

To remove milliseconds an alternative methode

```
In [1]: now = datetime.now(tzoffset('EDT', +4*60*60)).replace(microsecond=0)
In [2]: print now.isoformat()
2016-05-28T01:43:14+04:00
```

Comment: I added import dateutil and it appears to be working.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the microseconds? It is supposed to be mm:ss.sss

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope you are looking for this one.